# Ethernet not working on main comp, but works on laptop

Tags: windows-7, ethernet

So I've just recently moved into university accommodation (college over here in Australia) and the college goes through some crappy internet provider called Everywhere Internet. Anyways, I set up my connection with them and everything, and all was working fine. Had a relatively solid (but slow as) internet connection.

However the internet dropped out one night and I couldn't get it to come back up. I decided for some reason that it'd be best to unplug and reconnect the ethernet cable (I also went into the network and sharing control panel and hit the disable button on the network I was using) and ever since then I've had no internet at all. I called the Everywhere Internet people and they said that they could see my IP address and stuff and thought that my setup was fine, therefore it must be an issue on my end. This seems to be the case because when I plug the ethernet cable into my laptop it works perfectly (currently typing this on my laptop).

So does anyone know what the hell I did wrong and how I can fix it? As I'm at university accommodation I have no access to the router or anything.

P.S. I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: What does it say if you right-click on your desktop PC's network adapter and choose "diagnose"?

Comment: Not exactly sure if I did the right thing. I went into the Network and Sharing Center and then clicked on my Local Area Connection and diagnosed that. Let me know if I did the wrong thing. It says "Your computer appears to be correctly configured, but the device or resource (DNS server) is not responding"

Comment: If you don't get an IP address, or you get a self-assigned IP address (starts with 169), then it means that the network isn't accepting your PC's network card for some reason.
If you do get an IP address, DNS server and subnet mask that are similar than what you get with your laptop, then your PC is getting the right network connection info, but there's something preventing you from sending/receiving traffic to the network...

Have you tried pinging www.google.com? What about 8.8.8.8 (Google's public DNS server)? Do both of these fail, or just www.google.com? What is the error message?

Comment: It's not your PC's fault. I've seen the same thing in university accommodation when quickly switching the device connected to an Ethernet wall jack with another one. As you don't have access to the router, you won't be able to power cycle it, so can't really troubleshoot this very thoroughly. In my case, I found just leaving my PC connected and waiting it out was all I could do. It should start working within 24 hours.

Comment: The IP address, DNS server and subnet mask are all very similar to my laptop. When I attempt to ping 8.8.8.8 all the requests simply time out. Typing in ping www.google.com doesn't work at all for me, the window just closes (I'm probably doing it wrong though, I don't really know how to ping :p)

Comment: Hmm, how long do you think I'd have to wait Dan? The problem started nearly 24 hours ago now.

Comment: It varies. Try pinging something. In Vista/Win7, Type "cmd" in the start menu's search box then enter. (In XP type "cmd" in the Run box then press enter). Then type "ping google.ca" without the quotes, then press enter. See if that works. Also try by IP address: "ping 8.8.8.8" and see what happens. "0% loss" means the ping was successful.

Comment: You enabled your connection again... right?

Comment: It's enabled. The OP did a "diagnose", which would have re-enabled it had it still been left off at that point.

Comment: Also, when I tried pinging I got a 100% packet loss return. I'm guessing that's pretty unsuccessful.

Comment: Yes 100% loss means it was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

It's not your PC's fault. I've seen the same thing in university accommodation when quickly switching the device connected to an Ethernet wall jack with another one. It "confuses" the router- maybe it gets a bad entry in its routing table, I don't know. As you don't have any access to the router whatsoever, you won't be able to power cycle it, so can't really troubleshoot this very thoroughly. In my case, I found just leaving my PC connected and waiting it out was all I could do. Mine would almost always sort itself out within 24 hours.

*If you're feeling adventurous, you could try using MAC address spoofing.*

This would involve assigning your desktop PC your laptop's MAC address, fooling the router into thinking it is the same device- and (most likely) circumventing this problem:

http://www.windowsreference.com/networking/how-to-change-mac-address-in-windows-registry/

It doesn't take long, so worth a try if you really want to fix this fast. However, if it does work then be sure to change the MAC address on your laptop at some point, as the two devices won't be able to communicate on the same network until they each have different MAC addresses from each other.

Comment: Well that made progress but didn't fix the problem. Now I have internet access but still can't get onto any webpages or log onto any online things. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: What do you mean by having "internet access" without being able to "get onto any webpages or log onto any online things"? It sounds like you *don't* have internet access to me. What are you seeing that has improved? Also, after you've made that MAC change, make sure you reboot your desktop PC before you test it again so the settings apply properly.

Comment: What I meant was that in the Network and Sharing Center on the map it showed me as having internet access, also when selecting a network, it would say my ethernet cable has internet access. However, I tried playing around with some more settings and it's reverted back to it's original state of having no internet now. Not even sure what I did to make it do that, all I was doing was disabling and reenabling devices :/

Comment: Gotcha. Well I would try a reboot, then test it again, then in Command Prompt do this: "ipconfig /all" and see if your MAC address is still the one you set it to. Also, see if your DNS server, gateway, default IP, and IPv4 address all look valid. They should be similar to your laptop's equivalent settings.

Comment: Yup, all seems fine :( Still isn't working though. I'm thinking either there's some really obscure setting that's been changed somewhere, or the issue needs to be fixed by an IT guy with access to the router.

Comment: Can you ping the router? See what the "default gateway" IP is (this is the router's IP). What does it say? Now try pinging it. Does it say 0% or 100% loss?

Comment: 0% loss. /10chars

Comment: So you can talk to the router. This is purely a DNS issue- you are getting a perfectly valid IP. What does it say your DNS servers are in *ipconfig /all*?

Comment: What do you mean by what they are? I can see their addresses if that's what you mean.

Comment: Yes, what are the actual DNS server addresses? We might be able to fix this just by putting different servers in there.

Comment: 10.10.2.1 and 10.10.2.2, however in order to access my internet I have to log in through some homepage with this ISP (which I can't change because student accommodation), so I'm not sure if changing them work in this case. I did a ping to 10.10.2.1 and got 100% packet loss btw.

Comment: I would experiment with different DNS server values (at least temporarily). First, try setting it to *"Obtain DNS server address automatically"*. See if you can browse after that. Or try using the default gateway's address as your DNS server. Also you can try with 208.67.222.222 (preferred) and 208.67.220.220 (alternate) which are the Open DNS servers. *After each DNS server change, you must close then re-open your web browser or it will still remember the previous DNS server.*

Comment: Have to have Obtain Default DNS on all the time in order for it to work in the first place. I'll give it a try with those open dns things. Edit: They didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: What about if you manually set the same IPv4 address on your PC as the one your laptop was assigned? If you have the same MAC and *also* the same IP, surely the router would treat the desktop PC exactly the same as it treated the laptop? (And allow you to reach the internet.)

Comment: another thing to try would be to open a command prompt and type route print and post the results as a reply to give us a little more to go on.   It sounds like a DNS connectivity issue to me personally.

Comment: actually - if you can get on the internet using your laptop - run ipconfig /all on the laptop and ipconfig /all on the desktop you are having issues with.   Are the values for default gateway, dns server, subnet mask the same on both devices?  Can you ping 10.10.2.1 from your laptop but not from the desktop?  that would be a good test..

Comment: My laptop pings 10.10.2.1 fine, however my pc still just times out when I try to. About to go out, so can't really do the other tests now. I feel though that the issue is a setting somewhere on my computer rather than the ISP.

Comment: It might seem that way, but considering what caused the problem (changing the device connected to that Ethernet jack) I'm sure the router somehow got confused. It should sort itself out soon though (in my experience it takes around a day to start working again)